# C# Guessing Game - While Condition Looping

Tags: c#, arrays, string, while-loop

So I'm following a tutorial for creating a basic guessing game. The video in question doesn't have you use an array, but I wanted to see if I could get it to work. It took awhile to get a while statement that didn't throw and error, but now it has no errors and just loops even if the condition is typed by user. Being new am I missing something or programming it incorrectly in some way?

```
using System;

namespace AuthorDesigned_GuessingGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //LESSON 17
            Console.WriteLine("LESSON 17");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            string[] secretWord = new string [2];
            secretWord[0] = "Author";
            secretWord[1] = "author";
            string guessWord = "";

           {
            
            }
            while ((guessWord != secretWord[0]) || (guessWord != secretWord[1]))
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a guess for the secret word: ");
                guessWord = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("You Win!");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @godot: it is against Stack Overflow community guidelines to make any changes to code other than whitespace (indentation). Even a minor change such as yours, which arguably doesn't change the question or the logic of the code, should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the loop condition to AND

```
while ((guessWord != secretWord[0]) && (guessWord != secretWord[1]))
{
    Console.Write("Enter a guess for the secret word: ");
    guessWord = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Also you have 2 curly braces before the loop that are not really doing anything.

Comment: `&&` != `AND`... your statment should be something like: `You need to change the loop condition to AndAlso (&&)`.

Comment: `while ((guessWord != secretWord[0]) && (guessWord != secretWord[1]))` has curly braces at the front and back because when they are not there Visual Studios throws an error for `&&`  symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous answer and you can also use `while(true)` there like that:

```
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a guess for the secret word: ");
    guessWord = Console.ReadLine();
    if(guessWord == secretWord[0] || guessWord == secretWord[1]) break;
}
```